# I have a permanent residence card D - EU from Belgium

Tags: netherlands, belgium, working-visas

I was wondering if I could work and live in the Netherlands.

Comment: In short, yes, but the question is off topic for this site.  You should ask it on [Expatriates.SE], but it might be closed as a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/9586/2440.  Have a look at that to see whether you can differentiate your question sufficiently.